# Playing audio for a specific time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio, time

If you want to play some sounds and audio files (like for notification in button's click or for any other purpose) for a specific time ( like 2 seconds or 5 seconds regardless of how long or short that audio file is ) by your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

First, we create a DOM Audio object for our audio file by providing the path to that audio file.
then set loop to true, call play(), and at last call pause() after a specific time with the help of setTimeout().

```
funciton play( audio_path, time_in_milisec){
let beep = new Audio( audio_path);
beep.loop = true;
beep.play();
setTimeout(() => { beep.pause(); }, time_in_milisec);
}

play('beep.mp3', 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to code this yourself, or are you looking for a library to make this easier? You might want to check out [WadJS](https://github.com/rserota/wad)

```
let song = new Wad({source : 'https://www.myserver.com/audio/mySong.wav'})
song.play({
    env: {
        // The duration in seconds. It defaults to the length of the audio file, but you can manually set it lower to make the sound stop after a certain amount of time
        hold: 10 
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use fastSeek(position: double) to set the position to reproduce the song.

```
const value = 30

document.getElementById("your-audio").fastSeek(value);
```

See more here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/fastSeek

Comment: Answers should directly answer the question themselves. While it is okay to reference sources, and often recommended to do so, your answer should not be a link-only comment.